# FFMPEG - what is the meaning of gt(scene\,0.3)

Tags: ffmpeg, ffprobe

I'm using this command in order to detect the shot boundaries in FFMPEG.

```
ffprobe -show_frames -of compact=p=0 -f lavfi "movie=test.mp4,select=gt(scene\,0.3)"
```

By changing the 0.3 value I can get different results. As far as I know this 0.3 value should be the difference of consecutive frames. But I don't understand what difference that is. Is it some thing related to the dominant color? Can some one clarify a bit?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The filter command `select=gt(scene,0.3)` selects the frames whose scene detection score is greater then `0.3`:

`select`: the frame selection filter

`gt`: greater than (>)

`scene`: the scene change detection score, values in `[0-1]`

The method used is called [Sum of absolute differences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_absolute_differences). The relevant code can be found in [libavfilter/f_select.c](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/libavfilter/f_select.c) and [libavutil/pixelutils.c](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/d490b26fcb1b36c91099537a08d9a217d4782451/libavutil/pixelutils.c)

Comment: I was surprised that nobody linked to documentation, so here it is: http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#select_002c-aselect

Comment: any reason why it wouldn't work? I'm using 0.0003 and getting frames just fine on one machine, but on another I don't get any frames even with 0.0001 despite plenty of changes in the scene.